# I encounter the following error System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to make a program for entering / editing and deleting users in a MySQL database. The database is external.

I have tried to change SqlConnection several times

```
con = new SqlConnection ("Data Source = ip /; Initial Catalog = u181542750_arsob; Integrated Security = True");
```

Complete [CODE PASTEBIN](https://pastebin.com/kfWrnWLJ?fbclid=IwAR0xPxmnMR_uIrXmYlhs81_PSbnOx-SDEFAzllOcYBx5Py8dv27lYb_W5Mo)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=sql34.main-hosting.eu;Initial Catalog=u181542750_arsob;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INFO Archers (Nume,Prenume,Varsta,Sex,Categorie,E-mail,Telefon,CNP) VALUES (@Nume,@Prenume,@Varsta,@Sex,@Categorie,@E-mail,@Telefon,@CNP)", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nume", textBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prenume", textBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Varsta", textBox3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sex", comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Categorie", comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@E-mail", textBox4.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefon", textBox5.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CNP", textBox6.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 -
>   Could not open a connection to SQL Server)'
>
> Win32Exception: The network path was not found

Comment: What part of **The network path was not found** isn't clear?

Comment: I'm a beginner and I do not know what to do to fix this.

Comment: Hold on ... Looking at the tags and the code I get the impression that you're trying to connect to a MySQL server with an SQL Server adapter?

Comment: @stickybit: That's a SQL Server error message. I suspect this poster just added an incorrect tag.

Comment: I just want to connect to my external data base and, after the program, upload my data into it. https://imgur.com/a/fvZZ1In

Comment: @KenWhite They also used the PHPMyAdmin tag, which again suggests MySQL

Comment: @StephenKennedy: They also used (originally) a Visual Studio tag, and mention in the comments below Visual Studio and Server Explorer. ???

Comment: It's the first post on this site. Beginner. I want to learn. Thanks for helping guys .......... :|

Comment: Please clarify whether the database is "MySQL" or "Microsoft SQL Server". This is very important. Thanks.

Comment: Database is MySQL

Comment: It would appear that you are using the wrong DB Provider set.  MySQL is not SQL Server. `AddWithValue` is a bad idea too and plenty of internet stuff on why and wherefore on that too

Comment: First we used cmd.Parameters.add ("@ Name", textBox1.Text); but visual studio found errors and told me that this option is no longer valid ... idk

Comment: Because you are using MySql, you cannot use `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` in your code because those are specific to Sql Server.  You need to use `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand` instead in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Ping to see if it is up

```
ping sql34.main-hosting.eu
```

Check that you can access

```
telnet 31.220.20.81 1433
```

If you cannot then you need to check if port is closed, there is antivirus that is blocking, Integrated Security (windows user) is not created on that server or it does not have permissions to access that db.

Comment: From the beginning, phpmyadmin had all the permissions set. It is a database of a hosting that I have and is created and the option for the '' remote database ''